# SharePoint Search and Column issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, search-results, sharepoint-search

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I have a list and with a column named "Description" and it's type is multiple lines of text and accepts enhanced rich text.

Now the problem is when the users search for entries in the list it is not searching in this particular column, like if a user search for a word "xxyyzz" in the list it is not searching under description column but if I do a search with **Description:"xxyyzz"** the resulting search do includes content from description column.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with earlier search and why it is not looking into the description column by default?

Comment: Did you create the column directly in the list or as a site column?

Comment: The column is created directly in the list